# scrollable div if there is 3 element or more

Tags: javascript, html

I have a block whose number of user addresses (div) can be zero or one or more.I want if number of div is 3 or more then block be scrollable and The maximum height of the block is equal to the sum of the height of 3 addresses(3 div) 
or(max height myDIV= the height of address-details 1 + the height of address-details 2 + the height of address-details 3)

.but i don't know what is wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/tp8hc72k/3/

```js
var nodelist = document.getElementsByClassName("address-details").length;
if (nodelist >= 3) {
  maxhght = 0
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var elmnt = document.getElementById('myDIV').children[i];
    maxhght += elmnt.offsetHeight;
  }

  //alert(maxhght);
  document.getElementById("myDIV").setAttribute(
    "style", "maxHeight:maxhght;overflow: auto;width:100%");
}
```

```css
.address-details {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0.5rem
}

#myDIV {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <div class="address-details">The 1 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 2 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 3 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 3 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 3 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 3 address element in the document.</div>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `height` for scroll to appear rather than `max-height`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var nodelist = document.getElementsByClassName("address-details").length;
  if (nodelist >= 3) {
    maxhght = 0
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var elmnt = document.getElementById('myDIV').children[i];
      maxhght += elmnt.offsetHeight;
    }

    //alert(maxhght);
    document.getElementById("myDIV").setAttribute(
      "style", `height:${maxhght}px;overflow: auto;width:100%`);
  }
}
```

```css
.address-details {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0.5rem
}

#myDIV {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <div class="address-details">The 1 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 2 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 3 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 3 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 3 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 3 address element in the document.</div>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the last line with this one:

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").setAttribute(
"style", "max-height:"+maxhght+"px;overflow: auto;width:100%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the javascript? 
Since the height of one address div will be depending on the font-size you use, if you just put a `max-height` on the div of 3 times the font size ( `3em` ) + a little bit extra accounting for the borders ( `calc( 3em + 8px )` if you so desire, instead of 3.2 ), you get this behaviour automatically without any JS.

```css
.myDIV {
  border: 2px solid red;
  max-height: 3.2em;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDIV">
  <div class="address-details">The 1 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 2 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 3 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 3 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 3 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 3 address element in the document.</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="myDIV">
  <div class="address-details">The 1 address element in the document.</div>
  <div class="address-details">The 2 address element in the document.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it will also consider margins. I switched inner divs with spans to avoid margin collapse.

```js
let myDIV = document.getElementById('myDIV');
let elmnt = myDIV.children;
let computedStyle = null;
if (elmnt.length >= 3) {
  maxhght = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elmnt[i]);
    maxhght += elmnt[i].offsetHeight + parseFloat(computedStyle.marginTop) + parseFloat(computedStyle.marginBottom);
  }
  myDIV.style.maxHeight = `${maxhght}px`;
  myDIV.style.overflowY = 'auto';
} else {
  myDIV.style.removeProperty('max-height');
  myDIV.style.removeProperty('overflow-y');
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.address-details {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <span class="address-details">The 1 address element in the document.</span>
  <span class="address-details">The 2 address element in the document.</span>
  <span class="address-details">The 3 address element in the document.</span>
  <span class="address-details">The 4 address element in the document.</span>
  <span class="address-details">The 5 address element in the document.</span>
  <span class="address-details">The 6 address element in the document.</span>
</div>
```